# Can't install Open VPN repository / "sources.list.d" permission denied

Tags: 20.04, openvpn

I'm trying to install Open VPN using the official instructions available here:

https://community.openvpn.net/openvp.../OpenVPN3Linux

However, I'm failing at this step:

```
curl -fsSL https://swupdate.openvpn.net/repos/openvpn-repo-pkg-key.pub | gpg --dearmor > /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/openvpn-repo-pkg-keyring.gpg
```

The terminal prompts:

```
bash: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn3.list: Permission denied
```

What do I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It should be as follows:

```
curl -fsSL https://swupdate.openvpn.net/repos/openvpn-repo-pkg-key.pub | gpg --dearmor > | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/openvpn-repo-pkg-keyring.gpg
```

The `sudo tee` part takes care of permissions.

Comment: Good start.  Some words of explanation could be added.